# autofilter not including all rows when filtering using vba

Tags: excel, vba

For some reason autofilter is not including all rows with the information. I have about 40 rows with information but he is only including 15 of them (has you can see in the picture, it seems autofilter table puts at blue the rows numbers)

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set sht = ActiveSheet
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

If target.Row = 1 Then
    If target.Column > 1 Then
        If target.Column = 5 Then
            Cells(target.Row, 6).NumberFormat = "0"

            Cells(target.Row, 9).NumberFormat = "General"
            Cells(target.Row, 9).Value = "Figueira da Foz"
        End If
    End If

    With ActiveSheet
        Dim tableData As ListObject
        Set tableData = .ListObjects("Tabela1")

        If Not tableData Is Nothing Then

            With Range("A3")
                .AutoFilter Field:=1, VisibleDropDown:=False
                .AutoFilter Field:=2, VisibleDropDown:=False
                .AutoFilter Field:=3, VisibleDropDown:=False
                .AutoFilter Field:=4, VisibleDropDown:=False
                .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="*" & Cells(target.Row, 5).Value & "*", VisibleDropDown:=False
                .AutoFilter Field:=6, VisibleDropDown:=False
                .AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="*" & Cells(target.Row, 7).Value & "*", VisibleDropDown:=False
                .AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="*" & Cells(target.Row, 8).Value & "*", VisibleDropDown:=False
                .AutoFilter Field:=9, VisibleDropDown:=False
                If target.Column = 10 Then
                    If target.Value = vbNullString Then
                        .AutoFilter Field:=10, VisibleDropDown:=False
                    Else
                        .AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="" & Cells(target.Row, 10).Value, VisibleDropDown:=False
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        End If
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

if i place instead  With .Range("A3:A" & LastRow) it will give an error "Run-time error '1004': AutoFilter method of range class failed". The idea was for the autofilter to filter all data until the last filled row, not only 15

have no idea how to fix this, can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you modify the range for it to be a table (Menu item: Format as Table). They are much easier to handle in VBA.

When a filter does not apply to all the rows in a worksheet, there is no easy way to tell (which is what you are experiencing).
On the other hand, a table manages its own rows itself, i.e. it is able to grow if you add more data.

- Type of table in VBA: `ListObject`
- Assignment: `Set MyLO = Worksheets(1).ListObjects(1)`
  Or `Set MyLO = Worksheets(1).ListObjects("TableName")`
- Properties returning a range (do not forget to test `If Not MyLo.<Range as defined below> Is Nothing`).
  They allow to never have to write `SomeCell.End(xlDown)...`:

  - Header: `MyLO.HeaderRowRange`
  - Data: `MyLO.DataBodyRange`
  - Insert row (if no data in the table): `MyLO.InsertRowRange`
  - Totals: `MyLO.TotalsRowRange`
- Filter:
  `With MyLO.AutoFilter
  ...
  End With`

Comment: humm but it's a table the one i have, however for some reason when some people have added rows to it it did not inserted correctly or at least it was not counting has it was on table. The rows numbers in the left side only 15 of them were blue all the others to 38 were with no color.

Comment: humm a table name ??? i did not set any name for the table, i just clicked where it said table in the beginning to start it. where do i check is name ?

Comment: ohh found it is "Table1" the table name

Comment: well i did half what you said cause i was not sure how to use the With MyLO.Autoflter part... i will update main topic to what i have done and it seems to be working fine...

Comment: on the Field:=2 line is a columns with dates ... how can i set it a criteria to search in the format "yyyy mmmm dd" . When trying with Format(Cells(target.Row, 2).Value, "yyyy mmmm dd") does not work cause it's searching in a small different way (shows on the filter text box It's equal to "2019 February 11" however when testing it manually it show on filter title It's equal to ""2019 February 11""

Comment: The value and the text **displayed** are 2 different things. I suggest you record a macro with you doing that to see the corresponding VBA code. You should end up with something like e.g. `MyLO.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:=        xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(2, "1/11/2019", 1, "3/10/2019")`. Note the `2` in `Array(2, "1/11/2019", 1, "3/10/2019")` means "day". Use `0` to filter on the year, `1` to filter on year+month (but still specify a complete date).